# Good training total loss but inference give bad performance

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

I exported a graph from tensorflow using this command:

```
export_inference_graph.py --input_type image_tensor \
  --pipeline_config_path=/mnt/data/pipeline.config \
  --trained_checkpoint_prefix=/mnt/data/checkpoints/model.ckpt-1670059 \
  --output_directory=/mnt/data/output/2018-04-23-1
```

My network converges : 
[image: Loss Tensorboard]
However, when using the network to do inference, it is really fast but detects the wrong things or nothing at all.

I am using the inception model, any help would be amazing.

Thanks

Comment: You may be experiencing [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting). Do you use a validation dataset ? Are you logging other metrics than the loss ?

Comment: I used 80% training, and 20% test set, I'm using the object detection api so I'm using the metrics they give for tensor board. I initially thought it was overfitting however I took a example from the training set and tested it and it was unable to detect it.